# How can I make Gradle download optional dependencies automatically?

Tags: gradle, gradle-dependencies

When downloading dependencies using Gradle it seems to exclude optional dependencies. For example, I included Guava:

```
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
```

and it did not download the optional dependencies listed here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/19.0

I've been learning Gradle and porting a legacy app to use Gradle. That application had a Python script wrapper that always downloaded the optional dependencies and I've kind of hit a wall here.

Answer (score 1):

According to the description of the Maven's [Optional Dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html):

> If a user wants to use functionality related to an optional dependency, they will have to redeclare that optional dependency in their own project.

Gradle has the same behavior as Maven, if you want to use some transitive optional dependencies - you have to declare them manually.

You can try to find some workaround, but anyway, it seems to be a little odd, to include all optional dependencies by default, don't even check, whether are they really needed. Sure, you can try to port your logic to run existent Python script with Gradle to collect all optional dependencies into local directory and declare it as [file dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:file_dependencies).